# C -- Trouble with initializing dynamic list

Tags: c

I'm having trouble with the deal function in a blackjack program I am writing. Can anyone see what is going on? When I try to print in main(), I get a segmentation fault.

Cheers.

MAIN FUNCTION

```
int main(void)
{
    int i, j, k, purse;
    card deck[52];
    card *head_d, *temp_d, *current_d = NULL, *last_d, *head_p, *temp_p, *current_p = NULL, *last_p;



make(deck);  //CREATES THE DECK
shuffle(deck); //SHUFFLES THE DECK
deal(deck, head_d, current_d, head_p, current_p)

for(i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d: %d %c\n", i + 1, deck[i].face, deck[i].suit);
    }

temp_p = head_p;
while(temp_p != NULL)
{
printf("%d %c\n", temp_p->face, temp_p->suit);
temp_p = temp_p->listp;
}

return(0);
}
```

FUNCTION deal()

```
  void deal(card x[DECK_SIZE], card *head_d, card *current_d, card *head_p, card *current_p)
    {

    int i;
    card *temp_p, *temp_d;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if( i % 2 == 0)
        {
            temp_p = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
            temp_p->face = x[i].face;
            temp_p->suit = x[i].suit;

            if (current_p==NULL)
            {
                head_p=temp_p;
            }
            else
            {
                current_p->listp=temp_p;
            }
                current_p = temp_p;
                temp_p->listp = NULL;

        }
        else
        {
            temp_d=(card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
            temp_d->face = x[i].face;
            temp_d->suit = x[i].suit;

            if (current_d==NULL)
            {
                head_d=temp_d;
            }
            else
            {
                current_d->listp=temp_d;
            }
                current_d = temp_d;
                temp_d->listp = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be useful if you also post your main function where you get the segmentation fault.. or maybe where you call the deal(...) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the arguments to the `deal` function is *local*, meaning when you change their value in the function, the variables used when calling the function will not be changed. You need to pass those arguments *by reference*:

```
void deal(card x[DECK_SIZE], card **head_d, card **current_d, card **head_p, card **current_p);
```

The do e.g.

```
*head_p=temp_p;
```

in the function to set the variables.

Call as

```
deal(deck, &head_d, &current_d, &head_p, &current_p);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on this. Do I need to declare **head_d in main? Or can I just pass the pointers with what I have declared already?

Comment: @tyson Yes you pass the pointers as pointer to the pointers with the address-of operator `&`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to stare at the code for awhile to wrap my head around it. One last question: After I made the edits, the only error that I am getting is '162: request for member 'listp' in something not a structure or union.' Can you make heads or tails of that?

Comment: @tyson Since I didn't check your code thoroughly I don't know which arguments needs to be passed as references or not, so I passed them all as references, i.e. pointers to pointers. This means you have to use the pointer dereference operator (unary `*`) to use those pointers. However because of the operator precedence you may have to put the dereference in parentheses, like `(*current_p)->listp`.

Comment: THANK YOU!! You are truly a life saver. I also found an error in my conditional statements. Was not using the pointer.    `(*current_p == NULL)`. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You have uninitialized pointer variable `head_p` in your `main` function. Yet you are attempting to read data supposedly pointed by `head_p`. Of course, you will get segfault.

Comment: I was trying to initialize in the function deal().